# Rotate view around y axis

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

How to rotate a UIView around its Y axis using `CGAffineTransform` (or other)?
I've tried for example with:

```
self.image.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi)
```

but only rotate around Z axis.

Comment: Try  viewBase.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0, 1, 0)

Answer (score 0):

That is not what a CGAffineTransform *is*. You want a CATransform3D.

But you cannot set that on a UIView transform. You will have to set it on the view's `layer` (or on *some* CALayer).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410836-transform

Comment: Might want to see my online discussion: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch16.html#_transforms See especially the section on Depth, because a rotation on the y axis is just going to look like a squeeze unless you take further measures.